# Oncode 9250 in PLI

Tags: mainframe, pl-i

I am getting ONCODE 9250 error in PL1 due to which the submodule i am trying to call from CTL module is failing.  The error is:

> Fetchable procedure with entry "*******" could not be found.

Please help in resolving this issue

Comment: Have you included the LOADLIB where that procedure resides in your STEPLIB concatenation?